# Install Grub Boot loader in different folder on UEFI!

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, uefi, gpt

I am new in UEFI and I moved to GPT. I am now using windows 7 and 10 in dual boot.

I want to install Grub boot loader in a different folder, not in the EFI system partition/ESP. So, Windows boot manager will not be replaced by Grub and I can remove Linux and reinstall again without problem.

Is there any way to do this?

After searching in google I found that only one ESP partition can be created in a drive. So, If I install Grub in ESP then Windows boot manager will be replace in GPT?

Answer (score 2):

See [ArchWiki's entry on GRUB with UEFI](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Installation_2) (even if you don't run Arch, it's helpful to understand the general workflow). Basically, you can install GRUB alongside Windows' boot, and you should be able to select between them in your motherboard's EFI interface. See also [the page on dual booting with Windows](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows#UEFI_systems).

Mount the ESP to /boot, then:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=grub
```

Then follow [these instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Windows_installed_in_UEFI-GPT_Mode_menu_entry) to add Windows entries to GRUB.

[rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/index.html) or [systemd-boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot) might actually be better options for this, they finds Windows' boot entries automatically instead of having to add a custom GRUB entry.

If all else fails and you manage to ruin your windows boot, [it's relatively easy to restore](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/4/SLN300987/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-on-a-gpt-hdd-for-windows-7--8--81-and-10-on-your-dell-pc?lang=EN).

Comment: So, both entry  will be show in Bios and I can select which one is need for me?

Comment: It depends on your motherboard, but usually when you have it in EFI mode (CSP disabled), you can go to the boot menu (look at the display to see what key to press, usually F12), and then select from there  which you'd like to boot (grub or Windows)

Comment: Ohh I see. thanks for helping me, let me try and reply here whan happen. thanks again